# Fixing abstract types in self type

Tags: scala, types

Consider this:

```
object TypeProblem {

  trait A {
    type T
    val set = Set[T]()
  }

  trait B {
    def b()
  }

  trait FooBad { this: A =>
    type T <: B
    def x {
      set.foreach(_.b())
    }
  }

  trait FooOk { this: A =>
    type MyT <: B
    type T = MyT

    def x {
      set.foreach(_.b())
    }
  }

}
```

The compiler complains that value b is not a member of FooBad.this.T
So why does FooOk work where I define a new type MyT and assigning T to MyT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The self type of `FooBad` is expanded by the compiler to `FooBad with A` (so that you can still access the members you define yourself). That means that `T` gets the definition in `A`, and not the one in `FooBad`, as you'd expect. You can fix your code by changing the definition of `FooBad` to explicitly add your own type:

```
trait FooBad { this: A with FooBad =>
   ..
}
```

or even better by using subclassing

```
trait FooBad extends A {
  ..
}
```

It is my belief that in most cases self-types should be replaced by plain subclassing. It is simpler to understand, less scary, and leads to better encapsulation.

Comment: Glad to help. But please fix my name in your comment, the first letter is I, not L. :-)

Comment: Sorry, Iulian :) Thanks again.